# jquery validation. Field A OR Field B OR (Field C AND Field D)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How would you go about creation a jquery validator for this scenario?

```
A: <input type="text" id="A" />
OR
B: <input type="text" id="B" />
OR
C: <input type="text" id="C" /> AND D: <input type="text" id="D" />
```

So the user has to complete one of the rows, and if they choose the last row, they have to complete both fields.

The require_from_group doesn't quite hit the spot.

Thank you!

Comment: _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"_

Comment: Thanks for the link @Sparky. Apologies, I wasn't aware of the requirements. I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the `require_from_group` rule on A, B, C and D.
- Use the `required` rule on C only if D is filled out.
- Use the `required` rule on D only if C is filled out.
- You must use `name` attributes in order for this plugin to work properly.
  `<input type="text" id="A" name="A" />`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            A: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
            },
            B: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup']
            },
            C: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
                required: function () {
                    return $('input[name="D"]').is(':filled');
                }
            },
            D: {
                require_from_group: [1, '.mygroup'],
                required: function () {
                    return $('input[name="C"]').is(':filled');
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5FMT9/**

The validation is working exactly as specified, however, you still have some work to do consolidating and placing the messages.  [See the `errorPlacement`, `errorElement`, `wrapper`, `errorLabelContainer`, `errorContainer` and `showErrors` callback functions and options](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).